# Android drawBitmap draws a kind of checkerboard pattern

Tags: java, android

Okay maybe I'm missing something here but when I do

```
 canvas.drawRGB(0x80, 0x80, 0x80);
```

I get a clean and expected grey screen:
[image]

But when I use this code

```
pixels = new int[800*480];
...
for(int x = 0; x < 800; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < 480; y++)
        {
            pixels[x+y*800] = 0xff808080;
        }
}
canvas.drawBitmap(pixels, 0, 800, 0, 0, 800, 480, false, null);
```

My phone draws something like this: (note the 'checkerboard' pattern; which shouldn't be there)
[image]

The same happens in the emulator, so I guess I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: That's odd.  What happens if you set hasAlpha to true in drawBitmap since you are setting alpha for each pixel in the array?